# How to find word collocation in WordNet from a sentence with Stanford NLP CollocationFinder?

Tags: stanford-nlp, wordnet, collocation

Given a paragraph or a sentence. The task is to find all word collocation which is already hard coded in WordNet. To clarify, I'm  trying to find word collocation which already in WordNet from a given text, I'm not trying to extract word collocation from text based on their frequency of "appearing together". I read [Stanford NLP](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.0/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/CollocationFinder.html) and found that they have `CollectionFinder` class which might do the job. However, the constructor is:

```
CollectionFinder colFinder = new CollectionFinder(Tree tree, WordNetConnection wc);
```

I looked up `WordNetConnection` and found out it is an interface. [Here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.0/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/WordNetConnection.html)
I don't know how to find a way to have an instance of `WordNetConnection`. It looks like no class implement `WordNetConnection`. 
Please recommend any documentation which cover `CollocationFinder` and `WordNetConnection`.